# Having trouble connecting to a SQL Server database in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have created a user (`surveyapp`) in the database and server (and put in the master database), as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwNdO.jpg

I've also given that user as many permissions as I can on the table I'm trying to query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMBAS.jpg

And finally here is the code that's not working. It says

> Additional information: Login failed for user 'surveyapp'

when it tries to run:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server = tcp:k4i7bteriv.database.windows.net,1433; Database = Survey Database; User ID = surveyapp@k4i7bteriv; Password ={********}; Trusted_Connection = False; Encrypt = True; Connection Timeout = 30; "))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.dataset (Gender, Age, Drink_Freq, Show_source) VALUES ('" + Gender.SelectedItem.Text + "', '" + Age.SelectedItem.Text + "', '" + Drinks.SelectedItem.Text + "', '" + Show.SelectedItem.Text + "');";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(the *****'s are the actual password in the code, I just removed it in this snippet)

I've done all the permissions stuff I can think of, and I don't know why it won't connect. It does this whether I have it running via localhost, or if I publish it to Azure and run it off the web, so it's not a firewall issue. I was up until 6am last night trying madly to figure this out, to no avail :( any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the login name and password are correct?

Comment: I am 99.999% certain, but I am DEFINITELY not opposed to trying that at this point. Unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to reset user passwords in SSMS :s EDIT: figured that out, trying with new password

Comment: Sveniat: Azure SQL doesn't use SSMS for login management. Use the Azure Management Portal.

Comment: still failed with new password so that's definitely not it.

Comment: Is it the SQL Server Data Tools option in the management portal?

Comment: Create a user on the azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/). You can browse the server which contains your database, and then click on properties, and the users.

Comment: So I got the Data Tools up and can edit the permissions in Visual Studio, but the permissions i set with SSMS are still valid. All the changes I made, granting permission to surveyapp, are still there. BUT IT STILL DOESNT WORK!!!! *throws fists at SQL gods*